# What is the difference between "shopping online" and "online shopping"?

Tags: american-english, british-english

For example:
1. I like shopping online
2. I like online shopping

Do both have the same meaning?
Which one is commonly use?

Comment: Hopefully by protecting this question we won't see any more spammy links from the same company. Vsible to >10K users

Comment: Used as a noun, both should mean the same, but let us use it as verbs: "She shops online" sounds better than "She online shops." She is shopping online" sounds better than "She is online shopping"

Comment: If I intended to mean that I liked doing my shopping online, I’d use, “I like shopping online.”  if I intended to say that I like the whole concept of being able to shop online” i’d say, “I like online shopping.”

Answer (score 4):

Both sentences have the same meaning and they are grammatically correct because 'online' is both an adjective and adverb (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/).

In the 'shopping online' there's an adverb, in the 'online shopping' there's an adjective.

According to Oxford Living Dictionary:

***Adverb***

: By means of the Internet or other computer network.

‘*shoppers would rather pick up the phone than do business online'*

***Adjective***

: (of an activity or service) available on or performed using the Internet or other computer network.

‘*online banking’*